# Construction of a Manin triple

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie bialgebra and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ be its dual. My question is how to construct a bracket on the direct sum $\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g}^*$ such that we obtain a Manin triple? My guess is that there will be the sum of the brackets coming from $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$, but that there will be mixed terms too. Does somebody have any reference where this is explained explicitly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Lie algebra brackets $(\mathbb{g},b)$ and $(\mathbb{g}^*,b')$ a skew-symmetric bracket on the vector space $\mathbb{l}:=\mathbb{g}\oplus \mathbb{g}^*$ is given by
$$
[(x,\alpha), (y,\beta)]:=\left( b(x,y)+ad_{b'}^*(\alpha)y-ad_{b'}^*(\beta)x
,\, b'(\alpha,\beta)+ad_{b}^*(x)\beta-ad_{b}^*(y)\alpha \right),
$$ 
where $ad_b(x)y=b(x,y)$, $ad_b^*(x)=ad_b(-x)^*\in End(\mathbb{g}^*)$, and similarly for $b'$. The result is as follows:

**Theorem (Drinfeld):** There is a natural bijective correspondence between Lie bialgebras $(\mathbb{g},b,b')$ and metrical Lie algebras $\mathbb{l}$ with Manin decomposition $\mathbb{l}=\mathbb{g}\oplus \mathbb{g}^*$.

Reference: Drinfeld: Hamiltonian structures on Lie groups, Lie bialgebras, and the geometric meaning of the Yang-Baxter equation.

Comment: See also the book Poisson Structures of Camille Laurent-Gengoux, Anne Pichereau, Pol Vanhaecke, page 113.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde$:$ How is $ad_{b'}^{\ast} (\beta)$ is defined? This happens to be in $\text {End} (\mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast}).$ Then how do we act it upon an element $x \in \mathfrak {g}\ $? What's the identification you are using here? If you are using the bilinear form $\left \langle (x, \alpha), (y, \beta) \right \rangle = \beta (x) + \alpha (y)$ then one can check that it is non-degenerate and both $\mathfrak {g}$ and $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ are isotropic with respect to it. Hence it gives rise to a pairing $(\cdot, \cdot) : \mathfrak {g^{\ast}} \otimes \mathfrak {g} \longrightarrow k$...

Comment: ...given by $(\alpha, x) = \alpha  (x).$ So the map $\varphi : x \mapsto (\cdot, x)$ gives rise to an isomorphism between $\mathfrak {g}$ and $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast}$ which gives a way of identifying elements of $\mathfrak {g}$ by elements of $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast \ast}.$ So what I guess is that $ad_{b'}^{\ast} (\alpha) = {\varphi}^{-1} \circ \left (ad_{b'} (- \alpha) \right )^{\ast} \circ \varphi.$ But using this definition I find it hard to show the invariance of the bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ with respect to the bracket you are referring to here.